# How to correctly show search results?

Tags: ios, swift, search, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a contact list tableView with the [Avatar Image - Name]. And I want to search among this users. For this I created a struct [User.swift]:

```
struct User {
    let name : String
    let image: UIImage
}
```

And I search via:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    self.filteredUsers = self.users.filter({( user : User) -> Bool in
        let stringMatch = user.name.rangeOfString(searchText)
        return (stringMatch != nil)
    })
}
```

but it searches just by String part(among names) as expected. Now, how can I connect to it contact avatar images?

I save all in an array `var users = [User]()` as:

```
self.users.append(User(name: user.displayName, image: UIImage(data: photoData!)!))
```

So, how can I show images too near the contact name?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what contact avatar images you mean? Be clear, show example. You mean `image` from your `User` struct? You can use it directly from you `filteredUsers` array

Comment: @katleta3000 yes, exactly! It's an image from my struct. Can you help me, how can I use it?

Comment: `user.image` ? It will give you `UIImage` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get your user

```
let userForRow:User = self.filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
```

then access the image

```
userForRow.image
```

you can use a standard cell to display the image

```
cell.imageView.image = userForRow.image
```

in the datasource's `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath indexPath)

    cell.textLabel.text = user.name
    cell.imageView.image = user.image

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right you want to show a tableview with cells containing a name and an image. So then just create this cell in Interface Builder (or code if you want) with a label and an imageView and then when returning the cell for your table just set the name as text for label and the image as image for the imageView.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell : UserContactCell?

    let userAtIndexPath = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]

    let name = userAtIndexPath.name
    let image = userAtIndexPath.image

    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userContactCell") as? UserContactCell

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "UserContactCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "userContactCell")

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userContactCell") as? UserContactCell
    }
    }

    cell!.nameLabel.text = name
    cell!.imageView.image = image

    return cell!
}
```